# Python 3 Default Encoding cp1252

Tags: python, character-encoding

I recently ran into some problems decoding a handle (with errors mapping 0x81, 0x8D) from the Biopython module with an anaconda 4.1.1 python 3.5.2 installation on a sony vaio windows 10 system

After some research, it seems that possibly the problem may be that the default decoding codec is cp1252. I ran the code below and found that indeed the default codec is set to cp1252.

However, several posts suggest that python 3 should have set the default codec to utf8. Is that correct? If so, why is mine cp1252 and how can I solve this?

`import locale
os_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html),

> There is a platform-dependent default encoding […] In many cases, but not all, the system default is UTF-8; you should never count on this default.

and

> PEP 3120: The default source encoding is now UTF-8.

In other words, Python opens source files as UTF-8 by default, but any interaction with the filesystem will depend on the environment. It's strongly recommended to use `open(filename, encoding='utf-8')` to read a file.

Another change is that `b'bytes'.decode()` and `'str'.encode()` with no argument use utf-8 instead of ascii.

[Python 3.6 changes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html) some more defaults:

> PEP 529: Change Windows filesystem encoding to UTF-8
>
> PEP 528: Change Windows console encoding to UTF-8

But the default encoding for `open()` is still whatever Python manages to infer from the environment.

It appears that 3.7 will add an (opt-in!) mode where the environmental locale encoding is ignored, and everything is all UTF-8 all the time (except for specific cases where Windows uses UTF-16, I suppose). See [PEP 0540](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/) and corresponding [Issue 29240](https://bugs.python.org/issue29240).

Comment: Clarifying that I use .read() to parse the handle from the Entrez.efetch module. Is it then possible to specify the encoding like with open()?